# Consecutive wrapfigures of different widths

Tags: wrapfigure

I have to insert two pictures of different width one below the other on the side of a text, and wrap the text around. I'd like the pictures to stay close to each other, so I don't want any text but the captions between the images.

Therefore I tried to put both the pictures inside the same wrapfigure environment, as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A big square}
    \vspace{5mm}

    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{flushright}
    \caption{A small square}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

How do I get rid of the whitespace between the text and the second figure?

Comment: I won't do it. I will add `\centering` instead.

Comment: Don't use flushright - that's internally a list and adds space, use e.g. `\raggedleft` or `\mbox{}\hfill \includegraphics ...`

Comment: It is possible to manually insert a wrapfig in the middle of a paragraph (but not using \lipsum or \blandtext).  However, in this case it would look better to keep the width constant (especially with captions).